# ionic cordova build android failed due to AOT

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, angular2-aot

I am new to ionic. I have created new application using the ionic framework. But when I hit command ionic cordova build android --prod --release build failed with AOT exception..

Everything working fine if I hit command ionic cordova build android --release without --prod flag.

Error Message:

$ ionic cordova build android --prod --release
    Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform android --target cordova
    [14:03:18]  build prod started ...
    [14:03:18]  clean started ...
    [14:03:18]  clean finished in 2 ms
    [14:03:18]  copy started ...
    [14:03:19]  deeplinks started ...
    [14:03:19]  deeplinks finished in 47 ms
    [14:03:19]  ngc started ...
    [14:03:27]  typescript error
    Type AudioCategroyPage in C:/xampp/htdocs/study-baba-beta/src/pages/audio-categroy/audio-categroy.ts                                                      is part
    of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/study-baba-beta/src/app/app.module.ts                                                      and
    AudioCategroyPageModule in
    C:/xampp/htdocs/study-baba-beta/src/pages/audio-categroy/audio-categroy.module.ts! Please consider mo                                                     ving
    AudioCategroyPage in C:/xampp/htdocs/study-baba-beta/src/pages/audio-categroy/audio-categroy.ts to a                                                      higher
    module that imports AppModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/study-baba-beta/src/app/app.module.ts and
    AudioCategroyPageModule in
    C:/xampp/htdocs/study-baba-beta/src/pages/audio-categroy/audio-categroy.module.ts. You can also creat                                                     e a new
    NgModule that exports and includes AudioCategroyPage in
    C:/xampp/htdocs/study-baba-beta/src/pages/audio-categroy/audio-categroy.ts then import that NgModule                                                      in
    AppModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/study-baba-beta/src/app/app.module.ts and AudioCategroyPageModule in
    C:/xampp/htdocs/study-baba-beta/src/pages/audio-categroy/audio-categroy.module.ts.

```
Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
at C:\xampp\htdocs\study-baba-beta\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
at step (C:\xampp\htdocs\study-baba-beta\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
at Object.next (C:\xampp\htdocs\study-baba-beta\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:5                                                     3)
at fulfilled (C:\xampp\htdocs\study-baba-beta\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
at <anonymous>
[14:03:27]  copy finished in 9.27 s
```

My Deployment Info.
cli packages: (C:\Users\shaggy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.9.1
npm  : 5.5.1
OS   : Windows 7
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to paste the error in your question.not an external image

Comment: I have not authority to insert image inside question.

Comment: I meant the error text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had this issue, I will post my solution in case someone else needs it.

1 - Remove @IonicPage() from .ts files

2 - Delete .module.ts

Comment: :sir its not  possible for me because i am using lazy loading in my app so any another way to fix above issue?

Answer (score 11):

First I gonna past here the missing screenshot you linked:

[image]

Then, about the solution, the error msg tells you what's the problem respectively your `AudioCategoryPage` is contained in two modules, therefore:

- Are you using lazy loading? Remove `AudioCategoryPage` from `app.module.ts`

or

- Are you not using lazy loading? Remove (delete) `audio-category.module.ts`

Comment: thanks, Mr. David Dal Busco.
I have removed audio-category.module.ts from the project and this working fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello I am facing the same error, I deleted the xxx.module.ts but again the issue came in yyy.module.ts file. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.

And surely the solution is to delete the pagename.module.ts files and inside the page.ts file delete the @IonicPage tag.

However on nested pages DO NOT delete the .module.ts files.